# How to color the border of checkbox in css

Tags: css

I want to color the border of checkbox. I have written the below css -

```
input[type=checkbox] {
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;

            border: 1px solid #007dc6;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }
```

This works for chrome only. I don't want to write browser specific code in css. The css should apply to all latest browsers.

Comment: Checkboxes don't look the same in all browsers...they each have their own implementaton. You would do better to use the replacement method as mentioned in the answer below for full control and cross-browser comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Manipulating checkbox appearance is possible by hiding the default checkbox and styling our own checkbox using the `:before` element and `:checked` , `not(:checked)` selectors

An Example:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.space {
  height: 10px;
}
.checkbox * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
.checkbox > input {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox > label {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.checkbox > [type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  color: #777;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #777;
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  content: '';
}
.checkbox.radio-square > [type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.checkbox.radio-rounded > [type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border-radius: 25%;
}
.checkbox.radio-blue > [type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.checkbox > [type="checkbox"] + label:hover:before {
  border-color: lightgreen;
}
.checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 4px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -4px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="chkTest" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="chkTest">Task one</label>
  <div class="space">

  </div>

  <input id="chkTest1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="chkTest1">Task two</label>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/jc81o4x0/

Comment: the HTML in my code is 

<div class="col-md-1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="eventType" class="event-type">
 </div>

So it doesn't have label as the sibling to input[type=checkbox]. Can you suggest example for my html code.

Comment: checkbox without label, how will user know its purpose ? ?